# Should we fix or burninate [ghosting]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[ghosting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghosting) currently has 2 questions, no wiki, and no usage description. One of the questions is closed as too broad.

Can we either remove it for lack of necessity or add a proper description to prevent misuse?

Comment: Agreed, I see no reason for this tag.

Comment: Why bother removing it? Someone will add it back eventually.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not saying it should be removed, but we should do *something* with it and I'm not sure we need it. Hence removing is one of the options.

Comment: I see it's just 2 posts with the unclear tag. I would just have edited it out... anyways, seems that the consensus is to remove this so I gave it a go.

Comment: @DarkCygnus With your rep, I'd have too. But this is hardly my turf, so I left it to you lot. I just point and you can decide what to do with it. All working as intended.

Comment: @Mast I understand. Thanks for letting us know about this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the consensus and votes here seems that the tag should be gone. I agree with what David said in [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6259/73791) answer, so I proceeded to swap 'ghosting' for [communication](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication).

[image: trogdor]

Answer (score 5):

I don't see a reason to keep this tag. It currently is being used on two questions, one if which is closed. It is an overly-specific tag which won't really be helpful to users. Ghosting is really just a lack of communication, so the [communication](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) tag would be applicable instead.

Comment: Agree with this. Communication is a better tag here.

Answer (score -1):

Not everyone knows what "ghosting" means. However it's an apt and succinct word to describe a phenomena that is fairly common and that leaves victims blindsided about what happened.

It's a nice, compact word that is optimal for a Tag. The problem, I guess, is that not enough people know what it means. In Google Trends, [the term seems to be roughly increasing in usage since 2015-ish](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=ghosting).

I think it doesn't hurt to keep it, it will eventually get more use.

I would instead considering dropping "burninate"-- that's actually a word that almost no one knows about. The etymology appears to be from a web-based comic-strip, "Homestar Runner"?? Never heard about it. The only way I can guess what it means is by seeing it's context. It also comes off the tongue very awkwardly. Burninate deserves to be burninated. What an ugly word!

Comment: Off-topic, but ["burninate" is a familiar term in SE universe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/241919) for removing a tag. And I agree with you: I don't know what "ghosting" means, so can you help improving the tag [by adding an excerpt, and perhaps also the wiki](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1002)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks! I have edited added some Tag info for "ghosting". Burninate is strange, obfuscating word for a concept as simple as tag removal. I will agree to disagree, however.

Comment: Burninating all the peoples, and their thatched roof COTTAGESSSS!!!!

Comment: Seems that you have not yet met [Trogdor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121570/332286)

Comment: Trogdor? Nah, never played dungeons and dragons in high school. :-)

Comment: I said consummate V's. CONSUMMATE!!!